# track length of time an email is read?

Tags: email, analytics

I know it is easy to track when someone opens an email (providing he activates images). But today I came across [a site that claims they can track the approximate reading time](http://www.getnotify.com/).

Can anyone explain how that would work?

Comment: Any advances, I searching if that information is accurate.
Thanks in advance if you can show me some information.